# Is there a name for this fallacy?

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

From time to time I've come across (or have been briefly tempted by) something like the following absurd example:

'40% of Coloradans are Republican, therefore, 40% of Republicans are Coloradan."

Closer to the bone would be, "Most NBA players are Black, so most Blacks are highly athletic."

Is there a term for this sort of gaffe, of not just misapplying observations from a non-random sample to the population, but of confusing 'A implies B' with 'B implies A' as well?  It feels more complex than just taking an inductive conclusion as a deductive truth.

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting question, but it's off topic for SO; I think there might be an English usage stackexchange forum. That said, maybe you are thinking of "post hoc, ergo propter hoc"?

Comment: Hi Robert - I thought I directed this to "statistics" and "probability-theory." I would assume that the English Usage group would have to be given the term in question for them to assist, and that is what the problem was.  In any case, I believe a correct (or nearly so response) is, 'confusion of the inverse.'  Thank you.